# PHP Laravel: Datatables getting and error when displaying records in the table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I am trying to create a table using datatable server-side using yajra/laravel-datatable. I retrieve the data correctly but i am not able display the records in the table because of the alert error says: "DataTables warning: table id=table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7" below is my codes:

Blade.php:

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="table" class="display table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="tblTitle">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>User ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and my script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ url('blog.getData') }}',
        columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                { data: 'user_id', name: 'user_id' },
                { data: 'title', name: 'title' },
                { data: 'description', name: 'description' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

my Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Blog;
use Datatables;

class BlogManagementController extends Controller
{
    public function lists(){
       return view('blog.blog_management');
    }

    public function getData(){
        $blogs = Blog::select('id', 'user_id','title','description');
        return Datatables::of($blogs)->make(true);
    }
}
```

and my route:

```
    Route::get('blog', 'BlogManagementController@lists');
    Route::get('blog/getData', 'BlogManagementController@getData')->name('blog.getData');
```

and when i inspect/network, i got this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYEP7.png)

Comment: Did you read the page you linked to, it explains how to diagnose this problem and fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Ajax URL would be `{{ route('blog.getData') }}` instead of `{{ url('blog.getData') }}`.